# Prevent selection of history match in address-bar

Tags: google-chrome

A feature in Google Chrome is the suggestion when typing a search in the address-bar. I.e.:

╔═══════════════════╗
║ `foo bar` <kbd>⏎</kbd>                        :
╟
╙───────────────────╜

fool around. Then type:

╔═══════════════════╗
║ `foo b`                                   :

One get for example:

╔═══════════════════╗
║ `foo bar`                                 :
╟
║ `foo bar – Google Search`
║  foo b**aba**
║  foo b**x**
║  foo b**y**
╙───────────────────╜

The issue I have with this is that in the first suggestion is *auto filled* in the address-bar.

So: If I want to search for `foo b` I have to delete the trailing `ar`.

Very often I do a search like

> foo baz

Then want to search

> foo

But as `baz` is *auto-filled* I have to *delete* the `baz`.

This is insanely counter productive.

It is already as suggestion number one, first line below address-bar, and an arrow down stroke is much better then it cluttering the address bar.

So: any way to tune this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to prevent the top result from autocompleting the top result, however you can turn off predictions entirely in the settings: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95656?hl=en-GB